# Functions as arguments in relations

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

I have here a little problem, where I am just not really sure how to tackle this:

Let R be a relation on the real numbers, with R = {(log2(x), x)| x e R+}. Determine whether this is a function and if so, determine whether it is injective and/or surjective.

My problem here is that I am not quite sure how to look at this. The logarithm is clearly a function over the domain R+, but in the relation log2(x) would be the the argument for the function and x is the value of the function. Would it be correct to assume that this is actually defining the function f(x) = 2^(log2(x)) = x with R+ as the domain?

Comment: Not really but almost. It's defining the exponential $y\mapsto 2^y$, as it's the same set of ordered pairs.

Comment: Ok I understand now, in this case this would be 2^y. Thank you for your help I was just confused, whether the function defined by the relation was 2^log2(x) or just plain 2^y .

Comment: $R(\log_2x) = x$. So which function is that true for: $y \mapsto 2^y$ or $y \mapsto 2^{\log_2 y}$? In this case $y = \log_2x$, so is $2^{\log_2x} = x$ or is $2^{\log_2(\log_2x)} = x$?

Comment: Here is where the confusion starts kicking in with me: the way I see it is either 2^log2(x) or just plain 2^x (since log2(x) is the only arguments 2^x is going to receive). But wouldnt the domain differ, because for 2^log2(x) the domain is clearly only R+, wheres for 2^x the domain is R. So which one would be the correct one?